# JqueryUI autocomplete, Custom renderItem doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

Hi I have read a lot of answers on this one and followed the instructions but it is just not working for me.

> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){<br>
>   $(".header-search-box").autocomplete({
>     source: function(req,res) {
>         $.ajax({
>             url: "http://localhost:3000/autocomplete/"+req.term,
>             dataType: "jsonp",
>             type: "GET",
>             data: {
>                 search: req.term
>             }
>         });
>     },
>     select: function(event, ui) {
>     }
> }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul,item){
>     console.log('I am coming back')
>     return $("<li>").append("<a>"+item.model+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
> }
> ```
>
> });

This code is not working, the _renderItem function doesn't even print to the console.

Again I have followed all the suggestions in previous answers, any help would be appreciated

**Edit 1**

The Ajax success function is this

> ```
>  success: function(data) {
>                 res($.map(data, function(item) {
>                     return {
>                         : item.make + ' ' +item.model,//text comes from a collection of mongo
>                         value: item.model
>                     };
>                 }));
>             },
> ```

I am not sure how to translate that into the data object...

Comment: you have not set the source function response...

Comment: @j809 I have commented it out for testing purposes and removed it in the code above. let me add that... the reason I commented it out was I didn't know how to assign the response to the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your custom `_renderItem` with a local array source.

It works nicely and also gives the alert as set.

Take a look here : http://jsfiddle.net/XJ5En/

JS:

```
var tags = ["abc","bas","cqwe"];
$(".header-search-box").autocomplete({
    source: tags
}).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul,item){
    alert('I am coming back');
    return $("<li>").append("<a>"+item.value+"</a>").appendTo(ul);
};
```

There must be some error in assigning the response to the source. Please check it properly.

Comment: Your answer set me in the right direction, hence choosing it as the right answer. Thanks